# Value of structure variable is not printing as expected in pointer operation

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct type {
    int a;
    char b[10];
}MyType;

MyType* p;
void appenddata(MyType* p);
void cleanup(MyType* pointer);

void mycode() {
  p = (MyType *)malloc(sizeof(MyType));

  if(p != NULL)
  {
    p->a = 10;
    strcpy(p->b, "sample");
    printf("p->a - %d\n",p->a);
    printf("p.b - %s\n",p->b);
  }

  appenddata(p);

  /* set the values for p and do some stuff with it */
  cleanup(p);
  if(p != NULL)
  {
    printf("p->a - %d\n",p->a); << Why value I am getting is '0' here and 
    printf("p.b - %s\n",p->b);  << No value is printed here
  }

}

void appenddata(MyType* p)
{
  if(p != NULL)
  {
    p->a = 10;
    strcpy(p->b, "sample appenddata");
    printf("p->a - %d\n",p->a);
    printf("p.b - %s\n",p->b);
  }
  else
  {
      printf("p is null\n");
  }
}

void cleanup(MyType* pointer) {
  free(pointer);
  pointer = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    mycode();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
p->a - 10
p.b - sample
p->a - 10
p.b - sample appenddata
p->a - 0
p.b -
```

In above program why I am getting '0' and no data displayed in mycode function, it should be '10'and 'sample' should be printed, whats wrong with the program?, as far as I knows when we do cleanup then I am not passing as reference so it should not affect local copy of structure.
Please clarify my doubt

Comment: You are shadowing `p`, and `#include <stdlib.h>`. Turn warnings on.

Comment: Even after fixing Keine's noted problem, `pointer = NULL;` in pointless in `cleanup`. All that does is set a local pointer variable to `NULL`; the caller-side provided argument will remain unchanged (though it will be holding a now-dangling, invalid pointer value).

Answer (score 2):

Your program is having couple of undefined behavior.

**First undefined behavior:**

In the `struct type`, you have member `b` as an array of `10` characters:

```
char b[10];
```

And in the function `appenddata()`, you are copying a string of length more than `10` characters to `b`:

```
strcpy(p->b, "sample appenddata");
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Accessing array out of bounds is undefined behavior.

To resolve this increase the size of array `b`, like b[50], and use `strncpy` which gives you some control over the number of characters to be copied to the destination. Read about `strncpy` thoroughly before using it.

**Second undefined behavior:**

When you free a dynamically allocated memory block, its lifetime is over.

From C Standard#6.2.4p2

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address,33) and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime.34) **If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime**.
>   *[emphasis mine]*

Here, you are accessing the `p` after freeing it:

```
  if(p != NULL)
  {
    printf("p->a - %d\n",p->a); << Why value I am getting is '0' here and 
    printf("p.b - %s\n",p->b);  << No value is printed here
  }
```

which leads to undefined behavior. This is occurring because of the `if` condition `p != NULL` which will be `true` even after calling freeing `p` in `cleanup()`. In the `cleanup()` function, you are freeing pointer `p` but assigning `NULL` to local variable `pointer` of type `MyType *`. Instead, you should do `p = NULL;` after calling `cleanup()` function.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I knows when we do cleanup then I am not passing as reference so it should not affect local copy of structure. Please clarify my doubt

You are partially right.
In 'cleanup' you only have a copy of `p`. Assigning `NULL` to it does not change anything.

But you pass the value of global `p` to the function and then call `free`.
This does not change `p` but nevertheless frees the memory where it is pointing to.

After calling `cleanup` you are not allowed to access that memory location again.

Your expectation to get

```
10
sample
```

is based on a wrong assumption.
You could get any value as this is undefined bahaviour anyway.

BTW:
If the memory wasn't invalid, you would get

```
10
sample appenddata
```

This is due to the same reason.

In `appenddata` you don't change `p` but you change `p->b` which is still in place after you leave the function.

Comment: Even if I take local copy of  "MyType* p;" inside mycode function I am getting same result!!! #Gerhardh

Comment: If your `p` is a copy of global `p` then it will point to same memory and cause exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in `cleanup(p)`
You shouldn't do it before printing data.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid warnings related to `free` add `#include<stdlib.h>` to source, in cleanup you cleaning the structure data and de-referencing the local pointer instead of main pointer. hence the main pointer becoming dangling pointer.

Added some printf to demo:

```
Hello, World!
p->a - 10
p.b - sample
p->a - 10
p.b - sample appenddata
Pointer Address before cleanup : 0x14a5020
Pointer Address before free : 0x14a5020
Pointer Address after free : (nil)
Pointer Address after cleanup : 0x14a5020
p->a 1- 0
p.b 2-
```

Hence trying to print the garbage of dangling pointer pointed.

To avoid you can do either way.

Replace cleanup function as MACRO

```
#define cleanup(p) free(p); p=NULL
```

or return the pointer from cleanup funciton

```
MyType* cleanup(MyType* pointer);

....................
 /* set the values for p and do some stuff with it */
p = cleanup(p);
.......................

MyType* cleanup(MyType* pointer) {

  free(pointer);
  pointer = NULL;
  return pointer;
}
```